# iOS webview autofocus doesn't work on keyboard open

Tags: javascript, html, ios

I have an iOS app that uses a webview to open a website inside. The website will have some forms with textarea or input textbox.

On the webview, it will not focus on the textarea/input element on touch/click although it triggers keyboard open. So the keyboard will block the display element.

On mobile browser (Safari/Chrome), when I tap the textarea/input text it will focus on the element and the keyboard will not block the currently focused element.

I have tried adding the meta tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, height=device-height, target-densityDpi=device-dpi">`
```

on the html but the issue persists.

Tried to add `autofocus` on all the input text/ textarea too but still cannot resolve the issue.

Please help me out :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be related to the iOS version. iOS version 10 or below works perfectly fine while 11.1 has this issue. Newest iOS 11.2.5 seems to not have the issue though